# Install Arch Linux on MBP and remove mac OS

Tags: arch-linux, osx

I want to install Arch Linux on my MBP 2015 and remove Mac OS.

Is it possible to keep the Mac OS recovery partition, so when I want to go back to Mac OS I just need to start the recovery?

Output of diskutil list:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Youri:~ youri$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            190.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

I was trying to do a dualboot, but it won't worked so there are 3 more partitions, these 3 will be deleted:

```
   4:                        EFI NO NAME                 134.2 MB   disk0s4
   5: 4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709               16.1 GB    disk0s5
   6: 933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915               43.9 GB    disk0s6
```

Which partitions do I need to remove? Looks to me the "Macintosh HD" partition and the EFI partition, because you install a new Linux EFI partition?